# no project is connected to this web server.to configure projects go to web administrator

Tags: microstrategy

I'm new to Microstrategy development, for the first time installation of tool in my machine i created an report in the WEB executed well and very next day when I'm opening the WEB it showing "no project is connected to this web server.to configure projects go to web administrator". I Configured the Web Administrator twice and thrice but no luck. I reinstalled and checked but still same error. Search of this issue in the net and applied but same error.Please provide what is actual issue and how to get ride of it?Any solution provided is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm also faced the same problem after hours of surfing i haven't found any solution.Next day i tried to configured the Desktop to do any samples on it and after some time i tried to open the Web Application miracle it configured and showing my Desktop configured folder in the web.So once try to configure the Desktop and check the Web and tell the result of it

Comment: thanks for the reply let me check once and confirm you whether it was working or not.

Comment: it works but some more configurations taken for me to get the Web development.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your projects in 3tier in desktop, this is most likely because Web has been set to require the User to connect it to the Intelligence Server. Just go in web admin, look for your Intelligence Server, and click on the connect button.

Your projects should then show on the project screen.